# Trying to save zip to stream

Tags: c#, asp.net, dotnetzip

I'm trying to save streams of files to a Zip stream.

The code:

```
public static MemoryStream ZipFiles(Dictionary<string, byte[]> files)
{
    var output = new MemoryStream();
    using (var zip = new ZipFile())
    {
        foreach (var file in files)
        {
            var ms = new MemoryStream(file.Value);
            ms.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
            zip.AddEntry(file.Key, ms);
            zip.Save(output);
        }
    }
    return output;
}
```

It was working, but now on the 2nd time of loop on zip.Save it's throwing a ZipException with message "Cannot read that as a ZipFile". InnerException "object reference not set to an instance of an object".

Any help would be great.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use next code:

```
        var output = new MemoryStream();
        using (var zip = new ZipFile())
        {
            foreach (var file in files)
            {
                var ms = new MemoryStream(file.Value);
                ms.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
                zip.AddEntry(file.Key, ms);

            }
            zip.Save(output);
        }
        return output;
```